# Create polylines from CSV in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, csv

I have a CSV with 500 ship routes. 
Every row is a different trip and the columns have the values of `ship_name`, `lat_1`, `lng_1`, `lat_2`, `lng_2`,`lat_3`, `lng_3`... `lat_20`, `lng_20`

How can I insert this information in QGIS and create polylines between this coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Unlike other forums, we expect not only a statement of the goal, but a description of what you have attempted to meet that goal, and what problem you encountered during the attempt. Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: In the duplicate candidate, the solution using virtual layers is the way to go.